# htaccess file in Microsoft azure conversion to web.config

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config

I am trying to deploy a PHP application using native MVC framework in microsoft azure, I had it deployed but I found out that the .htaccess file is not readable and I have to convert it to web.config file.

I don't quite understand everything about rewrite scripts in the .htaccess file, can someone please have this converted to web.config file? I want my application to work as soon as possible so I do not have much time to study, but rest assured that I'll comprehend the changes you'll give me.

Please see my .htaccess file contents below.

File Number 1:

```
Options -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sols/secure

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

File Number 2:

```
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
```